# VM provisioning and task scheduling in cloudsim

Tags: cloud, scheduling, cloudsim

I am working on **CloudSim**. I am misunderstanding resource provisioning (e.g.: **VMs**) and task scheduling in cloud. Below are scenarios to explain my questions.

If we have 3 different types of VMs (different mips 250,500,750), and we need to schedule 3 tasks:

**Case 1:**

We have limited resources (5 VMs) **so how each vm map to the type?**

```
vm1     type 1, type 2 , type 3 
vm2     type 1, type 2 , type 3 
vm3     type 1, type 2 , type 3 
vm4     type 1, type 2 , type 3 
vm5     type 1, type 2 , type 3
```

After mapping (vm - type), we will have for example:

```
vm1     type 2 500
vm2     type 1 250
vm3     type 3 750
vm4     type 2 500
vm5     type 1 250
```

We need to schedule these tasks to minimise the makespan:

```
T1 length 1000 
T2 length 2000 
T3 length 3000
```

After scheduling based on minimising makespan will have:

```
T1 length 1000 to vm3
T2 length 2000 to vm3
T3 length 3000 to vm3
```

**What is the maximum capacity of vm to run the task? In other words, when we can use another VM?**

**Case 2:**

We have unlimited no. of VMs, how we map the VMs with its type? how we can create VMs on demand or dynamically?

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Which VM would have which type it's totally depends upon what `mips` you have passed to it during Vm creation.

For example:

```
mips=250
pesNumber=1
vm = new Vm(1, userId, mips, pesNumber, ram, bw, size, vmm, new CloudletSchedulerTimeShared());
```

This VM would have type1 and it can handle maximum 250 million Instructions of a task at a time because it has 1 PE.

If `pesNumber=2` than it can handle total 500 (mips*pesNumber) million Instructions of a task.

For **case 2** you can refer official [example no: 7](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/examples/CloudSimExample7.java) of Cloudsim in which VMs are being created at run time.

Hope it will help you.